# Yii Lazy Loading Getting values in through table/model

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii-cmodel

In Yii, I have a relations set up that use the through option.

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'users_relationships' => array(
                self::HAS_MANY, 'EnvironmentUsers', 'environment_id', 'together'=>true 
            ),
            'users' => array(
                self::HAS_MANY, 'Users', array('user_id' => 'user_id'), 'through' => 'users_relationships', 'together'=>true 
            ),

        );
    }
```

And I access it like :

```
 foreach($model -> users as $value):
    $model-> user_id;
    endforeach;
```

Which works fine when I want to access values in the Users model. But when I try to access a value in the EnvironmentUsers model, it throws the notice value cannot be found.

```
foreach($model -> users as $value):
    $model-> is_environemnt_administrator;
    endforeach;
```

My question is, how can I also access the the values in the through table when lazy loding in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second loop you should call the good related model!
It seems you are calling `users` instead of `users_relationships`

```
foreach($model->users_relationships as $value):
    $model-> is_environemnt_administrator;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Oh, so what I ended up doing is that, and when I want to get the users information, I lazy load on that model.